# SUM subquery with GROUP BY inside of it

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, subquery

I have a kinda peculiar query to run. I need to SUM the population value of different prefectures under each region as a column, and return it to the main query. For example this query:

```
SELECT region_en 
     , population AS temppop 
  FROM prefectures 
 WHERE region_id = 12 
 GROUP 
    BY region_en
```

returns this table:

```
Karditsa 129541
Larissa 279305
Magnesia 206995
Sporades 13798
Trikala 138047
```

All the above belongs to the same region id (12), and i need to get the SUM of all those populations under the same query. I tried applying the above but it is not working. I dont get the sum which is 767686 but 95960750 instead:

```
SELECT SUM(b.cases) as cases
     , COALESCE(SUM(o.poptemp), 0) as pop
  FROM prefectures AS b 
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT region_en
            , population AS poptemp 
         FROM prefectures 
        WHERE region_id = 12 
        GROUP 
           BY region_en
     ) AS o 
    ON o.region_en = b.region_en
 WHERE b.region_id = '12'
```

Basically I need the total Cases per region, as well as the sum of all people living under it.

Comment: The group by in the first query serves no purpose since there is no aggregation happening - it could produce incorrect results..

Comment: It is needed because the population is a fixed value for each row which holds the daily cases. Without it i wouldn't get all the individual prefectures and their population but a stream or rows..Take a look at this: http://prntscr.com/vjhzas

Comment: You should not be storing the population in every row in prefecture.

Comment: It could might as well be a Total_Cases or Total_Incubated number which would be an total number for each prefecture, which increments every day...It is the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for a window sum. Your original query is not a valid aggregation query, which makes things a little unclear.

If there is just one row per `region_en`, then no need to aggregate:

```
SELECT region_en, population, SUM(population) OVER() as region_population
FROM prefectures 
WHERE region_id = 12
```

You can get the same result for all regions at once like so:

```
SELECT region_en, population, 
    SUM(population) OVER(PARTITION BY region_id) AS region_population
FROM prefectures
```

If there really are several rows per `region_en`:

```
SELECT region_en, SUM(population) AS population, 
    SUM(SUM(population)) OVER(PARTITION BY region_id) as region_population
FROM prefectures 
GROUP BY region_id, region_en
```

Note that window functions are available in MySQL 8.0 only. In earlier versions, you would phrase the query as:

```
SELECT region_en, population, 
    (SELECT SUM(p1.population) FROM prefectures p1 WHERE p1.region_id = p.region_id) AS region_population
FROM prefectures p
```

Comment: I was just about to say that...It is a MySQL 5 server so i cant use the window functions.
Let me see what i can do with the last query you posted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually i used a different approach.

```
Select SUM(o.cas) as cases, SUM(o.pop) as population FROM
(SELECT a.population as pop, SUM(a.cases) as cas FROM prefectures a WHERE a.region_id = 12 GROUP BY a.region_en) AS o
```

This brings back the correct values and it is superfast as well.
In the end you get 2 columns:

```
cases population
2515  767686
```

which is the correct values.